# Passing a function foreach key of an Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, spark-graphx

I have an array like that :

```
val pairs: Array[(Int, ((VertexId, Seq[Int]), Int))]
```

which generates this output :

```
(11,((11,ArraySeq(2, 5, 4, 5)),1))
(11,((12,ArraySeq(7, 7, 8, 2)),1))
(11,((13,ArraySeq(5, 9, 8, 7)),1))
(1,((1,ArraySeq(1, 2, 3, 4)),1))
(1,((4,ArraySeq(1, 5, 1, 1)),1))
```

I want to build a Graph for each `pairs._1`. That means for example those who have the same id ( pairs._1 ) will construct a Graph together. 
I am thinking about passing a function of Graph Construction to every id.
How can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a function for each pairs._1"? Please provide a sample of the input and desired output.

Comment: @dcastro I have just corrected my post. Can you take a look ? Thanks.

Comment: do you already have the function that constructs the graph?  What have you tried?  Do you know about `groupBy`?

Comment: @BenReich Yes, I have the function. I join 2 RDDs together (vertex) and I construct an edge between them. `groupBy` does only the sort of the array as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`groupBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.Array@groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]) function followed by [`mapValues`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@mapValues[C](f:B=>C):scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,C]) to process each group.

```
pairs groupBy {_._1} mapValues { groupOfPairs => doSomething(groupOfPairs) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't have always 11 and 1. I have to make a general case !

Comment: How does that number (11, 1, etc) influence what happens next? Does it matter at all?

Comment: That number is given randomly so in every execution I will have two or three different numbers. Nodes who have the same number will be treated in the function of Graph Construction.

Comment: @OmarMasmoudi Can you update your question, and explain what function would you like to call for every pair / group of pairs? It's still not clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: Else, can I create a graph of two nodes (only one edge) without using a function ? It means, every two nodes have that same number will construct a graph apart.

Comment: I think that I wants ! I will test it and keep you up to date. Thanks for your help